# LWC navigation to web page

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a custom page which will update the password of the user and will have to redirect to my other public site.

Password is updating, but it's not re-directing to web page which i have given below. Please help me on this.

```
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";


export default class ResetPassword extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

navigateToWebPage() {
  alert('in');
// Navigate to a URL
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__webPage',
    attributes: {
        url: 'https://www.salesforce.com'
    }
}) 
}

updatePassword() {
  fields[ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
  fields[PASSWORD_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.password;

  const recordInput = { fields };

  updateRecord(recordInput)
    .then(() => {
      this.variant = "success";
      this.title = "Success";
      this.message = "Password Successfully Updated";
      this.navigateToWebPage();
      //this.resetPasswordsuccess = true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      (this.title = "Error creating record"),
        (this.message = "Failed to Update"),
        (this.variant = "error");
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using lightning community?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni No, It's salesforce Site.

Comment: @maniaccoder No error occurred.

Comment: So just to confirm.
Does it open a blank page or it just does nothing?
Does it open the alert dialog box?

Comment: @maniac corder it just does nothing

Comment: @maniaccoder I went to this way  `window.location.replace(
          "https://www.salesforce.com"
        );`   Not sure this is write way, But this is working as i expect. Please let me know It's a right way.

Comment: hi @user3214361, did you find out a way without using window object? Even I am trying the same, but not able to navigate. Nothing happens on the navigation.